# Non Ascii characters in data annotations with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, character-encoding, data-annotations

I'm trying to add some validation checks to my model in MVC web application like this:

```
    [Display(Name = "Şube")]
    public decimal BranchId { get; set; }
```

But non ascii characters like "ş, ğ" doesn't render correctly. I don't have any similar problems like this in website itself, it only happens in data annotation values.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you show the `BranchId` label?

Comment: I'm using this: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Branch.BranchName)